# MS SQL Server - query to delete records returns message "X rows affected" - records are not deleted

Tags: sql-server

I'm a novice with MS SQL Server. I know the basics and can perform basic table operations. I ran across something today that has my scratching my head. I'm trying to clean a few tables of obsolete information and get an odd message and result.

Imaging 3-5 table all which contain a field that tracks the entry date/time created called dteCreated. I can query for this and select rows as follows:

```
Select strHostname, dteCreated
From tblComputerProducts
Where (dteCreated < GetDate() - 90)
```

I want records more than 90 days old

I run this query and see 11,000 records.

Now I try to delete the records:

```
Delete
From tblComputerProducts
Where (dteCreated < GetDate() - 90)
```

The return is something like 11000 records affected.
I run the select query again and see nothing was actually delete.

How is this happening and how do I work around it?

Comment: slight detour...don't use getdate() - 90, you should use dateadd(day, -90, getdate()). The basic math logic will not work on all date datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: For the question at hand, do you have a delete trigger on the table? Without more details we are pretty much guessing.

Comment: Does your delete say `dbo.` and your select does not, or vice versa? Are these happening in two different query windows, and if so, are you sure they're both connected to the same server, the same copy of the database, etc.? Or are you performing one statement in the app and one in SSMS? If so, check to make sure your app's connection string doesn't use the `AttachDbFileName` connection string attribute. Finally, check to see if there are any triggers on the table, in which case the delete could be getting "prevented" either via `INSTEAD OF` logic, or rollback.

Comment: Hi Aaron,
I can select a specific record and try to delete it and get the same results.
I also tried deleting using a different field which gave the same results.

I looked and do see a disabled Delete Trigger on the table. I assume since it is disabled, it is not the cause for this. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I just tried this and got the same results:
select *
from ComputerProduct
where dteModified < (DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE()))

Shows 353 records
In the same query window on the same table:

delete
from ComputerProduct
where dteModified < (DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE()))
(353 row(s) affected)

Select query again shows 353 records.

Comment: Here is the content of the delete trigger:

USE [WOL]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CompProdDelete] on [dbo].[ComputerProduct] instead of Delete
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
END

Comment: How about dropping the trigger? I can't see any reason to keep that around, even if it is allegedly disabled.

Comment: I didn't expect that. I deleted the trigger and it works as it should now. I don't know much about them and I couldn't really tell what it was supposed to be doing.

Good job! Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you said that you were a novice, so you may need to understand that when you do an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE command on a table, there is the possibility of trigger(s) being invoked.

The one you mention in the comments (shown below) is an INSTEAD OF trigger.  It basically says, in this case that when a DELETE is executed against the table, don't do the DELETE, just run this trigger instead.

Normally a trigger will do some checking and/or some synchronisation and/or some logging and then actually do the DELETE of the records. In this case all it does is SET NOCOUNT ON, which is nothing.  In other words the trigger is there to stop records from being deleted.  It would have been nice if the author left a comment as to why.

This might be for historical, auditing or referential integrity reasons. Obviously this is not a database you have created yourself, so I am a little concerned that you have done something that the original creator tried to prevent.   You may want to double check to make sure that there are no references to the dbo.ComputerProduct data that are now orphaned.

You said that the trigger was disabled.  It's odd that it seemed not to be disabled.  Odd...

Cheers

```
USE [WOL] 
GO SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CompProdDelete] 
on [dbo].[ComputerProduct] 
instead of Delete 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```